# C# HttpClient Serialize/Deserialize new

Tags: c#, rest, generics, .net-core, serialization

I am writing a basis class to simplify REST API calls. I am now at the point to decide how to handle the requests and responses from the perspective of the Serialize/Deserialize objects.

Below is a POST request example. Basically it receives the path and handle the response using as JToken.Parse.

**Example**

```
public async Task<Uri> PostCreateAsync(string entitySetName, object body)
{
    try
    {
        using (var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, entitySetName))
        {
            message.Content = new StringContent(SystemTextJson.SerializeToString(body));
            message.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await SendAsync(message))
            {
                return new Uri(response.Headers.GetValues("OData-EntityId").First());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public interface IRecord
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Contact : IRecord
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    public string FullName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string JobTitle { get; set; } = null!;
}

var contact = new Contact()
{
    LastName = "Gil",
    JobTitle = "Developer",
    FullName = "Andre Gil"
};

var response = await _api.PostCreateAsync("contacts", contact);
```

First problem here. How to provide the api name "contacts" generic? Json decoration?

Second, the Id attribute cannot be sent through on POST operation. Of course, I could use JsonIgnore. But the "Id" must be sent through in case of PATCH or PUT.

Comment: It looks like you're already using JSON.NET (that's where JToken comes from). Why not just use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(...)`, e.g.?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, you are write and it should work as said. I will update the question, because the POST operation seems to be more complicated. I hope you can contribute here as well.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, just updated. Hope you can contribute here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the guidance in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help make sure you get a quality answer. The questions you're asking have been asked by others before: before asking, read what's already been asked and answered. If you cannot find an answer, then limit your post to a single question with a clear, correct answer. If you have a follow-up question, create a new question rather than editing the existing one.